# WCF SOAP - Remove namespace from child nodes

Tags: xml, wcf, soap

I am building a service and have a client that requires a specific format of xml that I am trying to receive in my soap service. The issue I have is that the namespace prefix is applying to child nodes when I need it to be only on the root node. Below is the soap envelope that is generated for request in soapui:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:contact.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:ContactNotification>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:Identifier>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ID>122</ID>
         </urn:Identifier>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <urn:Details>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ContactPerson>c</ContactPerson>
         </urn:Details>
      </urn:ContactNotification>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to keep the prefix on **< urn:ContactNotification >** but remove it from  **< urn:Identifier >** and **< urn:Details >** so the envelope should look like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:contact.com">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:ContactNotification>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Identifier>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ID>122</ID>
         </Identifier>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <Details>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <ContactPerson>c</ContactPerson>
         </Details>
      </urn:ContactNotification>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to use the XML Serializer in WCF as need to support xml attributes (example above is cut down version)

Here is the code for my classes:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute (Namespace="")]


public partial class Identifier
{

    private string idField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="")]
    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return this.idField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.idField = value;
        }
    }
}


using System.ServiceModel;

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlType(Namespace ="")]

public partial class Details
{
    private string contactPersonField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Namespace="")]
    public string ContactPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return this.contactPersonField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.contactPersonField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And these are my service Interface/Implementation:

```
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ContactService
{   
    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "urn:contact.com")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]

    public interface IContactService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        void ContactNotification( Identifier Identifier, Details Details);
    }
}

using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ContactService
{
    [ServiceBehavior(Namespace= "urn:contact.com")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public class ContactService : IContactService
    {
        [OperationBehavior]
        public void ContactNotification(Identifier Identifer, Details Details)
        {

        }
    }
```

Have hunted around but cannot find a solution for this.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find solution for this?