# WCF SOAP namespaces

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I need to host a SOAP service for an external client who requires a specific WSDL and therefore specific input and output soap payloads.  I've managed to get the payloads close but I'm having issues generating namespaces exactly how I want them on both the input payload and the output payload.

For example:
REQUIRED inbound payload:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:glen="http://www.glen.com/glen/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <glen:ProcessXMLMessage>
         <MessageID></MessageID>
         <XML></XML>
      </glen:ProcessXMLMessage>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

ACTUAL inbound payload:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:glen="http://www.glen.com/glen/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <glen:ProcessXMLMessage>
         <glen:MessageID></glen:MessageID>
         <glen:XML></glen:XML>
      </glen:ProcessXMLMessage>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The only differences here is that the namespace is used on the attributes, and from what I can see there is no native way to do this in WCF.  See another post on the topic that was never answered: [WCF SOAP - Remove namespace from child nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291500/wcf-soap-remove-namespace-from-child-nodes)

I also had an issue with formatting the WSDL to force mandatory attributes however I was able to get around that using this: http://thorarin.net/blog/post/2010/08/08/Controlling-WSDL-minOccurs-with-WCF.aspx

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've managed to solve this using Message Contracts rather than Data Contracts.  It's still limited but it does give slightly more control over the schema.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/using-message-contracts

Comment: You should post this as the answer and then self-accept when the timer is up.