# .NET WCF Soap 1.1 Parsing with Namespaces

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, soap, wsdl

Note: I am aware there are at least a few other StackOverflow posts (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47647378/wcf-soap-namespaces) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41291500/wcf-soap-remove-namespace-from-child-nodes)) that are asking a simliar question to this, but none ever got answered, so I figured I'd give it another whirl :)

I am trying to create a .NET WCF service based on a client's Soap 1.1 wsdl and .xsd schemas they have provided me.  They have also provided a sample input (the details have been changed in my example but the main issue is still here).

I used svcutil against the wsdl and xsd files to build the MessageContracts, and they mostly work, but only if I qualify *every element* with the given namespace.

In the example request I received, the namespace is only qualified in the root element of the request.

I have tried playing around with the generated [XmlElement] attributes, changing the Form between Qualified, Unqualifed, and None, and changing the Namespace to "", and every other thing I can think of, but I can't manage to get the XML parser to successfully parse the full request unless I use Form=Qualified and actually include the namespace prefix in every child element.

Question: Are there other attributes, or other properties on the attributes I already have, that allow the exact input my client will be providing?

Here is the service contract declaration and message contracts:

```
[ServiceContract(Name="MyService", Namespace = "http://www.mywebsite.com/webservices/beans")]
[XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal, SupportFaults = true)]
public interface IValidatePasswordService
{
    [OperationContract(Action="http://api.paysimple.com/sso/myRequest", Name="myRequest")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat(Style = OperationFormatStyle.Document, Use = OperationFormatUse.Literal, SupportFaults = true)]
    MyResponseMessage MyRequest(MyRequestMessage request);
}


[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class MyRequestMessage
{

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mywebsite.com/webservices/beans", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("data", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, IsNullable=false)]
    public Data[] MyRequest;

    public MyRequestMessage()
    {
    }
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("svcutil", "4.8.3928.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.mywebsite.com/webservices/beans")]
public partial class Data
{

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Order=0)]
    public string value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The provided input example looks like this:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <bean:MyRequest xmlns:bean="http://www.mywebsite.com/webservices/beans">
        <data><value>data1</value></data>
        <data><value>data2</value></data>
        <data><value>data3</value></data>
    </bean:MyRequest>
</Body>
```

However, when I use that request, I get a MyRequestMessage with an empty MyRequest array.
But if I add the "bean:" prefix to each child element, like this:

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<Body>
    <bean:MyRequest xmlns:bean="http://www.mywebsite.com/webservices/beans">
        <bean:data><bean:value>data1</bean:value></bean:data>
        <bean:data><bean:value>data2</bean:value></bean:data>
        <bean:data><bean:value>data3</bean:value></bean:data>
    </bean:MyRequest>
</Body>
```

Then I get all of the input values.

Any ideas of what I can try (besides attempting to ask the client to change the way they make their request)?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you generating proxy classes based on WSDL files to call WCF services?

Comment: @DingPeng Yes I am, but I am only using the /messageContract option, and just cherry picking the contract classes out, since I am creating the service here.

Comment: Do you want to remove the bean element in the child element? I think this is unnecessary. XML specifies that any prefix can be used, as long as it is associated with the correct namespace.

Comment: @DingPeng You're right. I talked to the client, and they said they are able to configure their request to exclude the "bean:" prefix on that outermost element, and that solved my problem (along with setting the namespace attributes on the child element types to empty string).